# cocos2dx : Change Array to Vector

Tags: arrays, vector, cocos2d-iphone

I need to change Array to Vector as it is being depracted in cocos2dx.
Earlier it was running but after deprecation its giving error.
As I am quite new to cocos2dx I am not able to resolve this issue.

### Here is my code:

```
int BaseScene::generateRandom()
{
//int  rn = arc4random()%6+1;
int  rn = rand() % 6 + 1;
Array * balls = (Array*)this->getChildren();

Array * ballsTypeLeft = Array::create();
//    if(balls->count() <= 7)
{
for (int j=0; j<balls->count(); j++)
{
Node * a = (Node*)balls->objectAtIndex(j);
if(a->getTag() >= Tag_Ball_Start)
{                
Ball * currentBall =  (Ball*)balls->objectAtIndex(j);
bool alreadyHas = false;
for(int k=0;k<ballsTypeLeft->count();k++)
{
if(strcmp(((String*)ballsTypeLeft->objectAtIndex(k))->getCString(), (String::createWithFormat("%d",currentBall->type))->getCString()) == 0)
{
alreadyHas = true;
}
}
if(alreadyHas)
{

}
else
{
ballsTypeLeft->addObject(String::createWithFormat("%d",currentBall->type));
}
}
}
}
//    CCLog("%d",ballsTypeLeft->count());
if(ballsTypeLeft->count() <=2)
{
// int tmp = arc4random()%ballsTypeLeft->count();
int tmp = rand() % ballsTypeLeft->count();
return ((String*)ballsTypeLeft->objectAtIndex(tmp))->intValue();
}
return rn;
}
```

---

How can I make this method working?
Please convert this method using Vector.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change cocos2d::Array to cocos2d::Vector, you must first understand it. cocos2d::Vector is implemented to mimick std::vector. std::vector is part of the STL in c++. cocos2d::Vector is built specifically to handle cocos2d::Ref. Whenever you add a Ref type to Vector it automatically retained and then released on cleanup.

Now to change Array to Vector in your code:

Store children this way:

```
Vector <Node*> balls = this->getChildren();
```

Access ball at index i this way:

```
Ball* ball = (Ball*)balls.at (i);
```

Add elements to vector this way:

```
balls.pushBack (myNewBall);
```

**EDIT** -

From what I understand, you want to get a random ball from the scene/layer. You can perform this by simply returning the Ball object:

```
Ball* BaseScene::generateRandom()
{
    Vector <Node*> nodeList = this->getChildren();

    Vector <Ball*> ballList;
    for (int i = 0; i<nodeList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ball->getTag() >= Tag_Ball_Start)
        {
            Ball * ball = (Ball*)nodeList.at(i);
            ballList.pushBack(ball);
        }
    }

    if (ballList.size() > 0)
    {
        return ballList[rand() % ballList.size()];
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

If there is no ball it will return NULL which you can check when you call the function. The code you have linked below seems to make use of Arrays outside the function. You need to make the changes to accommodate that. I suggest studying the [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Vector%3CT%3E) for Vector.

Comment: Its saying that can not convert from cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node*> to cocos2d::Vector<Ball*>

Comment: Ah yes, getChildren () will return a vector of Node*. You will need to cast it to use it has your Ball class. Edited my answer.

Comment: When using this way the loop "for(int j =0;j<balls->count();j++)" gives the error that "Expression must have pointer type" and if I provide pointer over there then this line "Vector <Node*> balls = this->getChildren();" gives error.

Comment: to get number of nodes in a vector use "balls.size()". Vector is an object not a pointer so you cant access its methods using "->", you need to use ".".

Comment: Now I am getting this error - "Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)' OnVisual c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits 1491 
"

Comment: Either post your updated code or tell us which line is causing an error.

Comment: I have uploaded the whole code at this link. Please check that once. I really need help.  http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/unknown-type-std-invoke--callable--types/29529

Comment: Look at the example of how you can use Vector in your method. Also read the documentation as mentioned above. Hopefully, that should get you in the right path.